# Importing attribute data with ImportXML google sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I have attempted to import price data from this site:

http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Rubber_turkey#

with this import xml code:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/"&SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","_")&"#", "//div[@class='GEChartBox']/div/@data-data")
```

where A3 is

```
Rubber turkey
```

but it says the imported content is empty, what am I doing wrong here?

Its the value contained in the data-data attribute of the div